# How can I merge two APFS partitions on the same drive?

Tags: disk-utility, apfs

I have a 140GB partition I would like to merge into an existing partition. Both are APFS formatted. How can I merge these two containers ?

- Container Disk2 is my MacMini OS Mojave 115.9GB
- Container Disk1 is 140GB empty that I want to merge to Disk2

[image: Terminal screenshot]

Comment: Please don't use screenshots for text as this prevents your text from showing up in search and in screenreaders. You can easily copy/paste from Terminal (and apply code formatting for it).

Comment: Many thanks to Giridharan-Ramasamy those commands did merge my empty space to my ssd !

 
sudo diskutil apfs deleteContainer disk0s3
 
sudo diskutil eraseVolume "Free Space" %noformat% /dev/disk0s3
 
sudo diskutil apfs resizeContainer disk0s2 0